# After git reset, trying to merge again, but not saying conflict

Tags: git, merge

I messed up the codes after I merged branch `feature-search` to `master`. So I am trying to redo the merge and fix the conflict again. So I `git reset hard -- eae8ee4`. `eae8ee4` is the commit before the merge.

Then I try to merge the branch to master again. It didn't show any conflict error. It seems the master still contains the merged codes. So how do I do a merge and fix conflict again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git reflog`, find the `HEAD@{...}` prior to that dreadful `merge` and do `git reset --hard HEAD@{id}` (where `id` is a number). This will revert your code to the state it was prior to that `merge`

Answer (score 1):

The right command is `git reset --hard eae8ee4`.

It seems you forgot the `--` to the hard `option`.

I advice you to always have a look to the git history (`gitk --all`) after doing git action to be sure the result is what you expected.

Comment: Things after `--` will be [interpreted as a path](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset). It should more likely be `git reset --hard eae8ee4`